# Right aligned div inside a header with a navbar breaks to other line

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm having a struggle trying to get a div inside a header with a navbar sicked to right margin:

```
<div data-role="header"> 
  <div id="profile_navbar" data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="profile_navb_right">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/aN396n8.png" />
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RAoRPLt.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Tried many things with css on `#profile_navb_right`, but it always clear the 2nd div to another line:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Just got it to stick on the same line, although, still sticking to left side instead of right

Comment: you can use `ui-grids` which is also used by `navbar`, and override CSS as in this example http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UAaeZ/

Comment: works like a charm, tyvm

Comment: You're welcome, i'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ui-grid` responsive layout to fix your problem. `ui-grid-a`, `ui-block-a` and `ui-block-b`. Also, its important to give `ui-grid` a class or an ID in order not to overrlap with other `ui-grid` layouts.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UAaeZ/)**

**Markup**

```
<div class="ui-grid-a navbar">
 <div class="ui-block-a">
  <div id="profile_navbar" data-role="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="ui-block-b">
  <div>
   <img src="img.png" />
   <img src="img.png" />
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-grid-a.navbar > .ui-block-a {
 width: 80% !important;
}

.ui-grid-a.navbar > .ui-block-b {
 width: 20% !important;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set your block's `float` properties to `left` and `right`.

```
#profile_navbar
{
    float:left;
    /* other stuff */
}
#profile_navbar_right
{
    float:right;
    /* other stuff */
}
```

Comment: goin to try that, much thanks, my only css on that print was: #profile_navbar {
 width: 75%;
}

Comment: Oh... My answer was just a blind guess. Edited it.

Comment: it worked fine, tho, it looks like header is just behind 1st div:
http://i.imgur.com/dYN39kO.png

Comment: You may want to wrap both divs in container div with background etc.

Comment: uhm is there some class to apply that background automaticaly ? cause its seems like a gradient

Comment: Try to add "ui-bar-a" class your profile_navbar_right. I've never worked with cordova, so it's kinda difficult for me to guess.

Comment: Add it to you container div. It's even better.

Comment: cordova doesnt seem to interfere with styling, and btw, it gets like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Q4phr/4/ , if its not ask too much, how the hell i do a wrap to make background on alll that bar , haha

Comment: just got it to work with the comment up there from @Omar tyvm